# How to change the axis labels from NESW to NOSW in the windRose function from the openair package?

Tags: r, axis-labels, openair, windrose

I am trying to change the axis labels for the cardinal points from the windrose plot from NESW to NOSW as I want to present my graph in German. Is there a simple way to do so?

I took the whole code from the windRose function and changed the part axislabs <- c("N", "E", "S", "W") to axislabs <- c("N", "O", "S", "W") in Line 410. I then saved it under a new name windRose_D.
I've downloaded the package lattice but I still get the error: Error in checkNum(mydata, vars = c(ws, wd)) : could not find function "checkNum".
I don't know where I can find the package with the checkNum function...

Is there maybe a easier way to change the axis labels without changing the complete function?

Comment: See this question about how to modify a function and make sure it is operating in the right environment... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331690/modify-package-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple way of passing a parameter to `windRose`, but you can modify the function itself.  By trial and error, using the `body` function to modify the elements of `windRose`, we can do the following...

```
library(openair)

body(windRose)[[70]][[3]][["panel"]][[3]][[11]][[3]][[9]][[4]][[2]][[3]][[3]] <- "O"

windRose(mydata)
```

[image]

Comment: Great thanks! This worked very well. I just came across another code with a different approach which also helped answer my question, as I also wanted to remove the title on the bottom and the stats in the bottom right of the plot.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76776068/removing-statistics-title-and-increase-legend-size-from-openair-windrose